# is there a way to call native java code from a webview in Android other than using addJavascriptInterface?

Tags: android, android-webview

There is a bug with the Gingerbread distribution and the addJavascriptInterface method
described here:
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=12987

Although there are some workarounds for the issue like this:

http://www.jasonshah.com/handling-android-2-3-webviews-broken-addjavascriptinterface/

or this:
http://twigstechtips.blogspot.com/2013/09/android-webviewaddjavascriptinterface.html

All of them are partial-fixes with some holes in them.

So I wonder if there is another way to avoid the addJavascriptInterface method to invoke
native code from the html inside the webview.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please note that the bug you reference only affects the Gingerbread emulator, and not real devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope and I trust there is no way to call native code expect `addJavascriptInterface()`, because that will be  big security-exploit in Android. Nobody should be able to call native code from browser - that could cause many different abuses.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using [`WebChromeClient.onConsoleMessage`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebChromeClient.html#onConsoleMessage%28android.webkit.ConsoleMessage%29) and `console.log` as a crude form of *asynchronous* communication between your JavaScript and Java code. You would need to "serialize" whatever information you need into a string and have your Java code parse that string and execute whatever functionality you need.

Similarly to `addJavaScriptInterface` it would be possible for any other piece of JavaScript to call `console.log`, so your Java code still can't fully 'trust' the caller, but this approach doesn't have the security vulnerability you mentioned.